# How do I only extract numbers between 2 specific words using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to pull numbers between 2 specific words using regex. The problem is that they are multiline. I am trying to extract these from a PDF so it has to be between these 2 words only

```
WORD1:
(23)
(56)
(78)
END
```

I tried this
`\((.*?)\)` and it pulls the numbers between () but I need it to only search between the words **WORD1** and **END** instead of the whole PDF.
Is there a way to do it ?

```
Expected Output:
    23
    56
    78
```

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori I am using .NET

Comment: what if there are other letter between `WORD1` and `END`? you need to be more clear.
What if its,


WORD1:
(23)
a
(56)
(78)
z
END?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori No there will be only numbers in between () , no other characters.

Comment: What if its, WORD1: (23) abc (56) (78) xyz END?

Comment: No, as I said before only numbers

Comment: please check my updated answer and demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `\G` construct

`(?s)(?:(WORD1:)(?=(?:(?!WORD1:|END).)*?\d(?:(?!WORD1:|END).)*END)|(?!^)\G)(?:(?!\d|WORD1:|END).)*?\K\d+`

https://regex101.com/r/il00WG/1

Explained

```
 (?s)                          # Dot-all inline modifier
 (?:
      ( WORD1: )                    # (1), Flag start of new set 
      (?=                           # Lookahead, must be a digit before the END
           (?:
                (?! WORD1: | END )
                . 
           )*?
           \d 
           (?:
                (?! WORD1: | END )
                . 
           )*
           END
      )
   |                              # OR,
      (?! ^ )
      \G                            # Start where last match left off
 )
 (?:
      (?! \d | WORD1: | END )       # Go past non-digits
      . 
 )*?
 \K                            # Ignor previous match up to here
 \d+                           # Digits, the only match
```

Comment: Wow that is very close but I am getting WORD1 in the results.

Comment: (?s)(?:([^(WORD1:)])(?=(?:(?!WORD1:|END).)*?\d(?:(?!WORD1:|END).)*END)|(?!^)\G)(?:(?!\d|WORD1:|END).)+?\K\d+

gives What I need

Comment: @Skynet - If my regex is working for you, there is no `WORD1` matched at all due to the `\K` construct. The capture group around `WORD1` is used as a flag to indicate a new block is being parsed. This so you don't just see an endless list of numbers. If you are getting `WORD1` in a list and don't want it, just remove the parenthesis around it. But, I want you to understand, `WORD1` is _NOT_ part of the match ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the global modifiers **`gm`** in your regex to match what you need.

https://regex101.com/r/c3VLdq/1

```
(\(.*?\))/gm
```

m is for multiline

**`m`** modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line

Comment: It will search the whole PDF which I want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, what I used are LookAhead (?=) and LookBehind(?<=) 
So in your case it would look like this (if Lookbehind is supported)

(?<=WORD1:\n)(.*\n)+(?=END)
Note the new line symbol after WORD1: if that symbol is omitted, you will get result starting from the line break

tested here 
https://regex101.com/r/qxPQqq/4